# how to change the default message displayed by tooltip when error occurs in dojo

Tags: dojo

whenever i submit the form without entering anything into the text field by default i get a mesaage "**please fill out this field**".

how do i change the message to first name is required

```
< html >

< head >< /head >

< body >

< form action="a.html" >

< label for="firstName">First Name: < /label > 

< input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" 

      dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"

      required="true" 

      propercase="true" 

      promptMessage="Enter first name." 

      invalidMessage="First name is required." 

      trim="true" 

/>< br>

< input type="submit" value="submit"/>

< /form>

< /body >

< /html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to set "missingMessage", too:

- http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/ValidationTextBox

Comment: i tried with that but still the default one is being displayed